# Converting database import from CP1257 to UTF8 in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

Thanks for reading my question.

I am working on a e-commerce site, that imports its data from an accounting software based on an old Access 95 database.

I connect to the accounting software with a **pyodbc** connection, take the data I need, and export to the e-commerce sites database with **mysql.connector**. Everything seems to be working fine, except the encoding.

I get

> à á æ è ë ø û þ

instead of

> ą į ę č ė ų ū ž

It seems that the Access95 database uses CP1257 encoding, but I don't understand why my CHARSET does not work in the following connector:

```
strcon = (r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
          r"Dbq=E:\Google Drive\_www\flamanda.lt\_nauja svetaine\db\20160104\flamanda.MDB;"
          r"SystemDB=E:\Google Drive\_www\flamanda.lt\_nauja svetaine\db\20160104\SYSTEM.MDW;"
          r"Uid=*****;Pwd=*****;"
          r"CHARSET=CP1257")

ACCESS_conection = pyodbc.connect(strcon)

ACCESS_cursor = ACCESS_conection.cursor()
```

I've tried writing everything from the following table (https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Nothing works